# Python 3 BeautifulSoup- Replace New Line with <br> After a Specific String Pattern

Tags: python, string, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am quite new to web scraping with Beautiful Soup, and I am having a little trouble with inserting `<br>` tags after a specific string. I have thoroughly searched on StackOverflow, but I am still having trouble.

I have a ResultSet of `<p>` tags.

Inside each of the `<p>` tags (i.e. the string) may look like something like this:

`'Random text here. \r\n\r\n More random text here. \r\n Maybe even more text here.'`

I want to replace all instances of `\r\n\r\n` and `\r\n\` with `<br><br>` (former does NOT translate into `<br><br><br><br>`)

I can find and extract the instances of the new line characters by using some regex, but I am unsure of how to put the string together with a `<br>` tag.

So at the end, my example would translate into:

`<p>Random text here. <br><br> More random text here. <br><br> Maybe even more text here.</p>`

I think I need to use the .append function at some point, but it seems that this only works immediately after a specific tag, not in middle of the string of a tag.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to substitue **\r\n** with **br** tag

```
>>> test = 'Random text here. \r\n\r\n More random text here. \r\n Maybe even more text here.'
>>> import re
>>> test = re.sub(r'\r\n', '<br>', test)
>>> test
'Random text here. <br><br> More random text here. <br> Maybe even more text here.'
>>>
```

Comment: I tried something like that. But that replaces the string, which in html literally turns into `Random text here. &lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt; ... etc. etc.`

Comment: Can you print the exact **ResultSet** on which you are trying to replace the line breaks?

Comment: `all_p_tags = page_soup.findAll('p')`
I tried accessing the NavigableString by doing `all_p_tags[0].string` or `all_p_tags[0].contents[0]`, just to see if I can make it successful on the first `<p>` tag. I tried to convert NavigableString to unicode string and apply regex, but no success

Comment: Also on the above response, no matter how many '\r\n' there are, it should translate into TWO `<br>` tags

Comment: @ChaewonMin Can you share the link or webpage which you are trying to scrape?